# Limpiar Lista ComboBox

Tags: c#

Me gustaría limpiar una lista de un ComboBox pero, por la forma en la que la cargo, me da error al intentarlo "No se puede modificar la colección Items cuando está establecida la propiedad DataSource."

```
idViajeProveedor.Items.Clear();
var dsViajeProveedor = new DataSet();
dsViajeProveedor = objProveedor.ObtenerListadoViajes(1); 
idViajeProveedor.DataSource = dsViajeProveedor.Tables[1];
idViajeProveedor.ValueMember = "idViajeProveedor";
idViajeProveedor.DisplayMember = "Nombre".ToString().Trim();
```

Comment: pasale un datasource vacio

Comment: ¿Cómo hago eso?

Comment: idViajeProveedor.DataSource = new DataSource(); asi de simple

Comment: Pero datasource queda como lo tengo escrito porque tiene que apuntar a la base de datos: idViajeProveedor.DataSource = dsViajeProveedor.Tables[1];